# Unable to update R

Tags: r, updates, installr

I have 4.0.2 version and I want to update it. So I install `installr` and I tried to use `updateR()`:

```
install.packages("installr")

library(installr)

updateR()
```

After `library(installr)` I got a warning message:

> Installation status:  FALSE . Removing the file:

> C:\Users\HP250~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2RQ7lv/R-4.0.3-win.exe   (In
> the future, you may keep the file by setting keep_install_file=TRUE)

> [1] FALSE

> Warning messages:

> 1: In download_fun(exe_URL, destfile = exe_filename, quiet = FALSE,  :

> downloaded length 20258816 != reported length 88237960

> 2: In shell(install_cmd, wait = wait, ...) : > 'C:\Users\HP250~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2RQ7lv/R-4.0.3-win.exe' execution failed with error code 1

but I continue with `updateR()`. Then it started loading but aftrer fe seconds (at 10-20%) stopped. I got an other warning message:

> The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the
> program.

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I deleted Temporary Files and problem solved. I don't know why, but everything is ok now.